# Firebase realtime database returns only one entry

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying the firebase realtime database and I am executing my first queries. I am using the Firebase Admin console for querying.
I now have a problem that I only get one entry back by a query when using ordering. My data structure looks like the following:

[image]

The query I am using is:

```js
firebase().database().ref('/Office1/Department1/HR').orderByChild('Rank').on('value', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnap){
    console.log(childSnap.val());
  });
})
```

As an output I only get:
{"Name":"Charles","Rank":1}

As you can see the ordering works, however it only shows one item instead of all 3 entries. 
Somebody knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the code you shared that explains why it would only retrieve one child node from the JSON you showed. Can you set up a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsfiddle/jsbin, so that I can have a look?

Comment: Hi Frank,thanks for your answer. Sure, I try to set it up on jsfiddle and will post it afterwards. Is the error maybe due to the fact that I created the entries Employee1,2,3, by hand?

Comment: Just the fact that you created them by hand can't be the reason. Data is data, no matter how it was created. I honestly don't know the cause. From what you showed, you should be getting all three results. Looking forward to seeing it in a jsbin or jsfiddle.

Comment: I just tested it without using the Firebase Admin console in a real application. And here it works. It seems like the Firebase Admin console can´t handle forEach properly.